# jQuery mouseover

Tags: html, jquery, css

Quería saber cómo se puede hacer la parte de "SKILLSET" de esta página: http://www.xaviro.com/

¿Cómo hago para que la imagen no quede a desnivel de las otras y la etiqueta p quede como en la página?
Para este post agregue el background blanco así es un poco más facíl identificar los elementos y como quedan cuando pasan el mouse por las "imagenes"
Si pudieran ayudarme tambien con el background que le aplica cuando aparecen las palabras.

Dato aparte: Si no usaba formato svg las imágenes se estiraban mucho cuando aparecía el texto arriba.

Yo lo estoy intentando y me quedó de esta manera:

```js
 //SKILLS MOUSE OVER IMG
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').on('mouseover', '.image-container', function(){
    $("#html", this ).first().text( "HTML5" );
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $( "#html", this ).first().text( "" );
  });
});
```

```css
.skills-container{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 65px;
  background: linear-gradient(#36bed9,#29bad7);
}
.col-xs-12{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.col-xs-12 h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.col-xs-12 .skills-hr {
  border: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: .1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,transparent,#ffffff,transparent);
  background-color:transparent;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
img{
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background: white;
}
.image-container{
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="skills-container" >
        <div class="skills" id="skills">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h2>SKILLS</h2>
                    <hr class="skills-hr"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container" id="#html-cont">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="../img/css.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src=""  alt="">                
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 image-container">
                    <p id="html"></p>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso que estas buscando hacer es un elemento básico de la web ya, se los conoce como [Tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!
me estaba volviendo loco jajajaj